# Remove css styles from specific page

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

I need to remove all theme *(both child and parent)* css styles from a singular page using functions.php in a child theme. Here's what I'm currently adding to the child's functions.php

```
// import parent and child theme css
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));}

// remove the parent & style css
function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'parent-style' );
wp_dequeue_style( 'child-style' );
wp_dequeue_style( 'parent-style-css' );
wp_deregister_style( 'parent-style' );
wp_deregister_style( 'child-style' );
wp_deregister_style( 'parent-style-css' );
```

I want to apply this **PREFIX_remove_scripts** function to only one page on the site. How can I best accomplish this? Or is there another suitable way? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: using functions.php you can check if the page id the one you want to disable the css for OR you can setup a custom php page and exclude the stylesheets

Comment: Would creating a custom php page be more efficient than using functions.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to target the specific page you need to remove the styles on. You can use `is_page()` to target a *page* page (as opposed to another post type) and pass a page ID, slug, title, or no argument to target *any* page.

```
function wpse_217881_remove_scripts() {

    // Check for the page you want to target
    if ( is_page( 'About Me And Joe' ) ) {

        // Remove Styles
        wp_dequeue_style( 'parent-style' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'child-style' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'parent-style-css' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'parent-style' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'child-style' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'parent-style-css' );
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you already are, but to be explicit, you should be calling the function that dequeue/deregisters the styles from an action hook - in this instance `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

*From the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):*

> Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_217881_remove_scripts' );

// Optionaly add a priority if needed i.e:
// add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_217881_remove_scripts', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solutiuon for me was to create a [template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) with different or no head.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).